# How to use the same database table for multiple owned navigation properties that are the collection of the same type with EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, database-design

*My examples are simplified*. I have a parent entity:

```
public class Site
{
    public SiteId SiteId { get; }
    private string _name;
    private ICollection<TranslatedValueObject> _publicName;
    private ICollection<TranslatedValueObject> _description;
}
```

And there is an entity that should be **owned**:

```
public class TranslatedValueObject
{
    public string Value { get; }
}
```

Here is my EntityType configuration:

```
public class SiteEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Site>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Site> siteBuilder)
    {
        siteBuilder.ToTable("site");

        siteBuilder.HasKey(x => x.SiteId);

        siteBuilder.Property(x => x.SiteId).HasColumnName("site_id");
        siteBuilder.Property<string>("_name").HasColumnName("name");

        siteBuilder.OwnsMany<TranslatedValueObject>("_description", descriptionBuilder =>
        {
            descriptionBuilder.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("_siteId");

            descriptionBuilder.ToTable("translation");

            descriptionBuilder.Property<SiteId>("_siteId").HasColumnName("entity_id");

            descriptionBuilder.Property<Guid>("TranslatedValueObjectId").HasColumnName("translation_id").HasColumnType("uuid").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            descriptionBuilder.Property(x => x.Value).HasColumnName("value");

            descriptionBuilder.Property<string>("PropertyName").HasColumnType("varchar").HasColumnName("property_name").HasDefaultValue("description");
        });

        siteBuilder.OwnsMany<TranslatedValueObject>("_publicName", publicNameBuilder =>
        {
            publicNameBuilder.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("_siteId");

            publicNameBuilder.ToTable("translation");

            publicNameBuilder.Property<SiteId>("_siteId").HasColumnName("entity_id");

            publicNameBuilder.Property<Guid>("TranslatedValueObjectId").HasColumnName("translation_id").HasColumnType("uuid").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            publicNameBuilder.Property(x => x.Value).HasColumnName("value");

            publicNameBuilder.Property<string>("PropertyName").HasColumnType<string>("varchar").HasColumnName("property_name").HasDefaultValue("publicName");
        });
    }
}
```

With this configuration I'm getting the following error:

```
'Cannot use table 'translation' for entity type 'Site._publicName#TranslatedValueObject' since it is being used for entity type 'Site._description#TranslatedValueObject' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'Site._publicName#TranslatedValueObject' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity typed mapped to 'translation'.'
```

Is it even possible to use one table for multiple navigation properties of the same type? If yes, what is a mistake in configuration?

P.S. I cannot get the suggestion provided after the error description also.

Comment: The entity class should represent the table structure in the DB, not the structure of the business-logic objects. So even if there is some hacky way to map one table to several entities or navigations, you shouldn't do it. Map the entity to your business objects, it is a bad practice to pass DAL entities to business layer anyway.

Comment: @Morse. I'm working in DDD. It's not a business, but a domain layer.

Comment: In the TranslatedValueObject class, try to add the primary key and the foreign key, code like this: `public class TranslatedValueObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get;  set; }
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        public Site Site { get; set }
    }`. More detail information about configuring relationships, please refer [this link](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship) and [this article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx).

Comment: @ZhiLv thank you, but that definitely won't work. As the name implies, it's a value object, and I don't need an identifier for it in my application. I made it a shadow property on purpose.